# NRU-алгоритм замещения страниц

Tags: c, ос, виртуальная-память

Я пытаюсь реализовать NRU-алгоритм замещения страниц. Сам алгоритм выглядит следующим образом:
Разбить все страницы, которые находятся в физической памяти на 4 класса:

```
класс 0: R-Bit = 0, M-Bit = 0
класс 1: R-Bit = 0, M-Bit = 1
класс 2: R-Bit = 1, M-Bit = 0
класс 3: R-Bit = 1, M-Bit = 1
```

После этого нужно выбрать страницу РАНДОМНУЮ страницу из низшего не пустого класса. Это урывок моего кода. Он работает и страницы замещает с одним минусом - он ищет страницу минимального класса(т.е. банальный поиск минимума) и возвращает эту страницу как кандидат для замещения. Проблема в том, что это не рандомная страница.

```
if ((processTable[pid].valid) && (processTable[pid].pageTable != NULL))
    for (page = 0; page < processTable[pid].size; page++) {
        if (!isPagePresent(pid, page)) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (getPageClass(pid, page) <= minPageClass) {
            minPageClass = getPageClass(pid, page);
            pageToRemove = page;
            frame = processTable[pid].pageTable[page].frame;
        }
    }
```

Другая моя идея была : создать 4 структуры данных под каждый класс(например массив) и странницу каждого класса добавлять в структуру данных, а потом уже с помощью рандома извлекать из структуры данных. Но это выходит слишком сложный код и мне кажется, что есть более простой способ, как можно найти рандомную страницу не прибегая к использованию 4 структур данных....Т.е. по сути есть:

```
СТРАНИЦА КЛАСС
1          2
2          1
3          3
4          0
5          1
6          0
```

И из этих всех лишь страницы 4 и 6 являются минимальными  и нужно вернуть рандомную из этих двух.

Comment: Не претендую на истинность, но ИМХО «случайная» в данном контексте можно понимать как «первая попавшаяся, но не одна и та же каждый раз». Это не криптография, где  всё только на ней держится... Так что можно просто начинать новый поиск со следующей страницы после найденной в предыдущий раз или же собственно начинать со случайной страницы.

Comment: Если будут страницы в памяти с классами вроде { 7, 0 } (страница 7, класс 0) и {5, 0} (страница 5, класс 0). Допустим первая найденная страница будет выгружена из памяти и на ее место приходит новая. Это будет работать, если новая страница имеет класс повыше, чем предыдущая(например возникает следующая ситация {1, 2}{7,0}). Но что если класс новой страницы, тоже 0? Например {1, 0}{7,0}. Тогда при следующем проходе алгоритма вновь будет возвращена страница {1, 0}. Если я правильно Вас понял конечно. Подобная идея была у меня с самого начала(что по сути является поиском минимума).

Comment: в этом примере второй будет вытеснена {7,0} т. к. в следующем поиски она будет первой. [оформил всё как ответ]

Answer (score 2):

Не претендую на истинность, но ИМХО «случайная» в данном контексте можно понимать как «первая попавшаяся, но не одна и та же каждый раз». Так что можно просто начинать новый поиск со следующей страницы после найденной в предыдущий раз.

Псевдокод:

```
int page = processTable[pid].last_swap_page + 1;
int size = processTable[pid].size;
int minPageClass = 9000 + 1;
int stop_page = page ? page -1 : size - 1;
for (page; page != stop_page && minPageClass != 0; page=(page+1)% size) {
    if (!isPagePresent(pid, page)) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (getPageClass(pid, page) < minPageClass) { // строгий поиск
        minPageClass = getPageClass(pid, page);
        pageToRemove = page;
        frame = processTable[pid].pageTable[page].frame;
    }
}
processTable[pid].last_swap_page = pageToRemove;
```

Диаграмма работы алгоритма (5 физических/8 реальных страниц):

```
Адрес/страницы
&0| {1,2}     {1,2}     {1,2}     {1,0}     {1,2}     {1,2}     {1,2}
&1| {2,0}  1  {6,2}  2  {6,2}  3  {6,0}  4  {6,0}  5  {2,2}  6  {2,2}
&2| {3,3}  ⇒  {3,3}  ⇒  {3,3}  ⇒  {3,1}  ⇒  {3,1}  ⇒  {3,1}  ⇒  {9,2}
&3| {4,2}     {4,2}     {7,2}     {7,0}     {7,3}     {7,3}     {7,3}
&4| {5,3}     {5,3}     {5,3}     {5,1}     {5,3}     {5,3}     {5,3}


1) Надо загрузить {6}*       | очевидно выбирается &1, запоминаем i=1
2) Надо загрузить {7}        | начинаем поиск минимума с i:=i+1 == 2 выбираем &3 ({7,2}), запоминаем i=3
3) Сработал таймер           | Сброс битов R
4) Чтение {1;5;7};запись {7} |
5) Загрузка 2                | начинаем поиск с i:=i+1 == 4, выбираем i=1 ({6,0}), запоминаем i=1
6) Загрузка 8                | начинаем поиск с i:=i+1 == 2, выбираем i=1 ({6,0}), запоминаем i=2
```

- У новой страницы гарантировано установлен флаг R (не по своей же прихоти же менеджер памяти решил её загрузить), по крайней мере до следующего сброса.

Comment: `for (int page; page != last_page && minPageClass != 0; page=(page+1)% size)` вместо переменной `last_page` имеется в виду переменная `stop_page`, верно?

Comment: @EvheniiVasylenko, да; fixed

Comment: Значение 9000 + 1 лишь стартовое значение для сравнения и может быть любым, верно?

Comment: конечно;), менее весёлое значение было бы `max_page_class + 1`

Comment: Начальным значением могло бы быть 3, т.к. это наивысший класс. Вообще суть идеи я уловил. Это то, чего мне не хватало. Но есть еще пара вещей, которые я не совсем понял. Я честно стараюсь понять, но не понимаю. А именно:
`int stop_page = page ? page -1 : size - 1;`
`page=(page+1)% size`

Comment: это обычный обход кольцевого массива в памяти. 1)если начинаем с ненулевой страницы, то заканчиваем на `page -1`, а если с нулевой, то последней, `size - 1`;  2) как только page превысила размер пула страниц, начать считать с нуля. В целях оптимизации можно деление по модулю убрать, разбив на два цикла: от (page— size-1) и (0—stop_page)

Comment: Тут, кстати, есть небольшой баг/фича: для stop_page цикл не прогоняется, так что последняя загруженная страница никогда не будет выгружена на следующей итерации...

Comment: Тяжело назвать это багом. Скорее особенности реализации алгоритма